# Building own iOS Static Library - Linking with other frameworks

Tags: ios, frameworks, hyperlink, linker

I'm trying to build a static library with a bunch of views and other classes...
They deal e.g. with emails, pdfs,... thus I need to link to some of the iOS frameworks like MessageUI and CoreGraphics e.g.

Somehow that doesn't work or I make another mistake.

Although I included those frameworks I get a ton of errors for example CGFloat is an unknown type or UIImage is unknown.

A sample iOS project with all library classes directly included and with the same frameworks linked, works perfectly. But outsourcing those to a framework doesnt work...

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which project doesn't compile now? the library, the other project in which you use the library or both?

Comment: *"Although I included those frameworks I get a ton of errors for example CGFloat is an unknown type or UIImage is unknown."* You get those errors in which project? If you get them in the library, how did you create the library project and how did you link it with the frameworks?

Comment: I get all errors in the library... I created it using the XCode template and I added the other frameworks like CoreGraphics by adding them in the target's build phases "Link Binary With Libraries"... all in the library

Comment: Ok, final question, `UIImage` is in UIKit, did you include it?

Comment: I did. I have also a separate project, without the custom library Im trying to build. This one includes all of the source code directly and also includes the iOS frameworks. This one compiles without any errors and works fine...

Comment: But if I try to split the example code from the library and as a first step, just try to build the framework, without any example project or anything, I can't even build the library because I get these errors although I include the same iOS frameworks/libraries

Answer (score 4):

You have to add

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

into the precompiled header of your library, as only Foundation is included by default

Comment: For CGFloat you should add
    #include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>